# BabylonJS, how to rotate mesh instead of the camera?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

http://babylonjs-playground.com/#A83GX#0

Hi All,

I have been playing with babylonjs for a couple of days now and excited about it. But why would I be here if I don't have a problem.

Attached the playground link, right now an arcrotatecamera rotates around a mesh. It gives an illusion that the mesh itself is being rotated, but when I move the object away from (0,0,0) it starts to show that the camera is rotating and not the object. Instead of such a camera hack, I would like to rotate the mesh itself from wherever it is, I googled and found a couple of topics in the babylonjs forum, but the solutions are not as smooth or eased as the camera solution. It will be great if someone can help me on this. Cheers and thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the rotate function?

Try `cylinder.rotate(new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 1, 1), 30);` ... It will rotate the cylinder mesh, 30 degrees in all axises iirc. Here's an [updated playground.](http://babylonjs-playground.com/#A83GX#1)

If you want to rotate your mesh using mouse input, here's how to rotate your mesh around X and Y axises with a few pointer events:

```
var onPointerDown = function (e) {
    // check if we clicked on a mesh
    var pickInfo = scene.pick(scene.pointerX, scene.pointerY);
    if (pickInfo.hit) {
        currentMesh = pickInfo.pickedMesh;
        rotationInit = currentMesh.rotation.y;
    }
};

var onPointerMove = function (e) {

    dragDiff = {
        x: e.x - dragInit.x, 
        y: e.y - dragInit.y                     
    }

    var newRotation = rotationInit;
    newRotation.x = rotationInit.x - dragDiff.x /70
    newRotation.y = rotationInit.y - dragDiff.y /70

    currentMesh.rotation = newRotation;
    return true;
};
```

You could also rotate around Z axis by adding some code (such as listening for a key, like Shift).

[Updated playground](http://babylonjs-playground.com/#A83GX#4)

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm not looking for the rotate function. I'm looking for a way to attach rotate function of the cylinder to the mouse, so instead of the camera being rotated the cylinder will be rotated. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried rotating the cylinder in your playground, it doesn't seem to work. But I got help from babylonjs forum at html5gamedevs.com. Here is the updated playground link. It's very similar approach to yours using pointer events but slightly different code, the event it attached to the canvas rather than the cylinder or the mesh, which is good for my purposes and more user friendly for my application :). 

http://babylonjs-playground.com/#A83GX#7

Comment: It does. The link is at the bottom of my answer. Yours is much better though.